# Warning: Illegal offset type in

Tags: php, arrays, class, offset

I have some problem with this code. Warning: Illegal offset type in Line 22

`$this->word[$kata][]=array($i,$j);`

and the full code is below

```
private $jmldoc = 0; private $word = array();

public function getIndex($D) {
    $this->jmldoc = count($D);

    for($i=0; $i<$this->jmldoc; $i++) {
        $pp = new prePro($D[$i]);
        $kata = $pp->tokenize();
        $n = count($kata); 
        for($j=0; $j<$n; $j++) {
            $this->word[$kata]=array($i,$j);
        }
    }
}
```

Can you help me to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You are passing an array, not a string/integer index to your $this->word.

```
    //I suppose from the context of your code that $kata is an array also
    //so if that's true, it can't be used as an index
    $this->word[$kata][]=array($i,$j);
```

Keep in mind that $this->word is an array. So probably there is something wrong with your program logic. To fix this, use an integer or string to access the elements of an array.

Comment: Just ran into this issue when I realised that SimpleXML always returns object, not string...